# How to send token string (jwt) as Cookie in Alamofire Post request in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, token, alamofire

I want to pass a token which is a jwt (json web token) something like

> ?eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.vNLenIyy1bdLShrNZHx7mKfbvJmDKsMEEsk2EIHYis0

and is in String format. I want to pass this token as Cookie to API in a Alamofire POST request. Please, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try setting the HTTPCookieStorage in the session.

**Swift 2**

```
let properties = [
    NSHTTPCookieDomain: "httpbin.org",
    NSHTTPCookiePath: "/post",
    NSHTTPCookieName: "foo",
    NSHTTPCookieValue: "bar",
]

let cookie = NSHTTPCookie(properties: properties)!
manager.session.configuration.HTTPCookieStorage?.setCookie(cookie)
```

**Swift 3**

```
let properties = [
    HTTPCookiePropertyKey.domain: "httpbin.org",
    HTTPCookiePropertyKey.path: "/post",
    HTTPCookiePropertyKey.name: "foo",
    HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value: "bar",
]

let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: properties)!
manager.session.configuration.httpCookieStorage?.setCookie(cookie)
```

Comment: Thank you! Got the concept.